# Kinect V2 Software works on Windows 8.1, Doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: windows, kinect

I have Kinect v2 Software that works perfectly on Windows 8.1 but on Windows 10 I receive:

```
The thread 0x22e4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Tien.Nhan\Documents\SIMIS\AIMS USER Tracking Research\OpenCV_Kinect_Blow_V2\OpenCV-WPF-KinectV2-master\KinectWPFOpenCV\bin\Debug\KinectWPFOpenCV.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Kinect.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

The program '[8404] KinectWPFOpenCV.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

None of the sample code from the V2 Kinect SDK works either with the same issue. I've tried several projects that work on windows 8.1 but can't seem to get it to work on Windows 10. I think its a dependency issue but am not sure what.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue might be in the .NET framework. Even with windows 8, if you install the .NET 4.6.0 or higher the Kinect v2 stop's working...

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I'll try deleting 4.6, thanks for your response!

Comment: Hmmm, it didn't seem to work, but I'll have to try reinstalling my 4.5 .net framework just in case. I'll let others know when I've tried it.

Comment: Yes, try the .net 4.5.2 - it might work. But I think that for windows 10 the Kinect v2 is not yet prepared... let's wait for a new SDK release hopefully

Comment: Yea I would have to agree because on my other computer that its working, the hand cursor for kinect just randomly dissapears even though it works perfectly fine on Windows 8.1. Thanks for the guidance!